# Angular: cannot create service via Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create service via Angular CLI and it is throwing the following error:

```
$ ng g service services/client
E:\MyApp\MyAngularJS proj\ng5\12Proj\clientpanel\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:89
            throw new InvalidConfigError(common_tags_1.stripIndent 
InvalidConfigError: Parsing 'E:\MyApp\MyAngularJS proj\ng5\12Proj\clientpanel\.angular-cli.json' failed. Ensure the file is valid JSON.
Error: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 511
    at Function.fromConfigPath (E:\MyApp\MyAngularJS proj\ng5\12Proj\clientpanel\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:89:19)
    at Function.fromProject (E:\MyApp\MyAngularJS proj\ng5\12Proj\clientpanel\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config.js:67:46)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\MyApp\MyAngularJS proj\ng5\12Proj\clientpanel\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build.js:10:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Removed `node_modules` and ran the `npm install` still getting the error above.

Uninstalled Angular CLI and installed globally again.

Comment: `ng generate service [name]` give forms.

Comment: It does say clearly that your .angular-cli.json has invalid json. Did you check that? Post it here maybe

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth Tried it with ng generate service also. Still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution for this problem.

This error happens when you generate angular project through angular CLI via command prompt and try to run before the dependencies are completely finished

`ng new clientpanel` using any text editor. - used web storm

1. Using command prompt. I have executed the above command.
2. I have opened the project via web storm on the other hand
3. It looks like all the files are created and have some content in it ( even in package.json)
4. so when I generate component using angular cli it works fine
5. but for services, it actually has broken. similarly, guards were also broken

So anyone who is in hurry to create the project. You have to watch out once the dependencies are successfully installed. Then you have to serve the application.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have often problems with angular CLI. I solve my problem by reinstall cli. I sound like a bad practice, but atm i haven´t found any better solution. Mostly happens, if switching between cli versions.